# Intent para chamar FACEBOOK

Tags: android, facebook, intent

O seguinte é esse disparar uma intent e a mesma chamar o app do Facebook. Consegui para enviar email

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setType("plain/text");
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("test@gmail.com"));
sendIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm"); sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new
String[]{"PRAQUEM@gmail.com"});
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ASSUNTO");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "TEEEXTO");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Poderia adaptar esse código para chamar o app do face? Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook é um site e não um aplicativo nativo do google, então você tem três opções:

- Chamar um webView (não precisa de uma `Intent` necessariamente) ou usando navegador nativo
- Chamar o aplicativo do facebook, será necessário o app do facebook estar instalado.
- Usando a API oficial

### Intent com aplicativo do Facebook:

Como eu disse é necessário ter o aplicativo instalado, conforme esta [resposta do soen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4191847/1518921)

- Apenas para inicar a tela padrão:

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
  intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");
  startActivity(intent);
  ```
- Para iniciar o inbox:

  ```
  String uri = "facebook://facebook.com/inbox";
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
  startActivity(intent);
  ```
- Outras telas:

  ```
  facebook://facebook.com/inbox
  facebook://facebook.com/info?user=544410940     (id do usuário, somente numeros)
  facebook://facebook.com/wall
  facebook://facebook.com/wall?user=544410940   (irá mostrar apenas informações visiveis para amigos, caso contrário redireciona para outro activity)
  facebook://facebook.com/notifications
  facebook://facebook.com/photos
  facebook://facebook.com/album
  facebook://facebook.com/photo
  facebook://facebook.com/newsfeed
  ```

### Usando o pacote oficial

Este é mais complicado, mas lhe permite algum controle a mais

- Registre-se https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android
- Crie um nome de um aplicativo
- É requirido no minimo a API 15: Android 4.0.3
- Crie as chaves
- Importe o `com.facebook.FacebookSdk`
- Siga a documentação https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

### Usando o navegador padrão instalado

O código a seguir irá usar o navegador padrão, pode facilitar se o usuário usa o navegador para se conectar no facebook, pois assim provavelmente já estará logado (não testei)

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

### Usando webView

O código a seguir irá usar o webView:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
setContentView(webview);

...

webview.loadUrl("http://facebook.com/");
```

Neste caso você poderá usar a interface de javascript para detectar os eventos ou disparar eventos, basta usar `addJavascriptInterface`

Comment: Era isso mesmo! wooow brigadão!